# Formatting Date in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I format this datetime attribute `2017-10-15` or how can I get the 15th of the current month?

```
@today = Time.now
@mid = time.strftime("%Y-%m-15")
```

into `October 15, 2017`? I tried using `to_formatted_s(:long)`, but it gives an error of undefined method.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: It looks like your variable time isn’t the class you’re expecting it to be. Figure out what class it is and see what methods are available to you for that class. You’ll likely need to change classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In Rails 4 or above

```
> Date.today.beginning_of_month + 14
#=> Sun, 15 Oct 2017 
# formatted as per your requirement
> (Date.today.beginning_of_month + 14).strftime("%B %d, %Y")
#=> "October 15, 2017"
```

**[Date#beginning_of_month](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Date/Calculations/beginning_of_month)** it will return you beginning date of month of specified date (which will be always `1st`, add `14 days`) so you will get `15th` of that `month`

Answer (score 1):

```
Mydate = "2017-10-15"
Mydate.to_date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
=> "October 15, 2017"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @GaganGami solution, you can create a `Date` class method `middle_of_current_month`

```
class Date
  def self.middle_of_current_month
    (today.beginning_of_month + 14).strftime("%B %d, %Y")
  end
end

Date.middle_of_current_month
#=> "October 15, 2017"
```